# how to display facebook url's in touch site format in iphone

Tags: ios4, facebook-graph-api

hi
i want to display a facebook profile of another friend without asking him to show login dialog. i am using fbconnect api. if i give http://www format it is showing page in standard format if i use http://m it doesn't showing full content in mobile view.
i want to use touch site on iphone app to show another user profile
how can i do that in touch site?
Pls help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add `?display=touch` to the end of the url, so the full url would be `http://m.facebook.com/WHATEVER_GOES_HERE?display=touch`